# R How to replace elements of a group only when all elements are zero

Tags: r, data.table

I have the data.table `dt` to which I want to add a new column `new_col` only when all elements in the group are zero.

```
library(data.table)
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
group <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c")
dt = data.table(a, group)
dt[]
   a group
1: 1     a
2: 2     a
3: 3     a
4: 0     b
5: 0     b
6: 0     c
7: 0     c
8: 1     c
```

Following is the code I tied.

```
dt[, new_col := ifelse(all(a == 0), NA, a), by = group]
dt[]
```

The output I am getting is

```
   a group new_col
1: 1     a       1
2: 2     a       1
3: 3     a       1
4: 0     b      NA
5: 0     b      NA
6: 0     c       0
7: 0     c       0
8: 1     c       0
```

The expected output is

```
   a group new_col
1: 1     a       1
2: 2     a       2
3: 3     a       3
4: 0     b      NA
5: 0     b      NA
6: 0     c       0
7: 0     c       0
8: 1     c       1
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we can use `if/else` as `ifelse` requires all arguments to be same length `all(a == 0)` is of length 1, along with the 'yes' but 'no' is not of length 1, which leads to recycling

```
dt[, new_col := if(all(a == 0)) NA else a, by = group]
```

-output

```
dt
   a group new_col
1: 1     a       1
2: 2     a       2
3: 3     a       3
4: 0     b      NA
5: 0     b      NA
6: 0     c       0
7: 0     c       0
8: 1     c       1
```

---

Or may also use `.I` to get the row index of the negated expression (or use `any`), extract (`$V1`) and assign those elements from 'a' to new_col.  By default, the other elements will be NA

```
dt[dt[, .I[!all(a == 0)], group]$V1, new_col := a]
```